# android SupportMapFragment lifecycle

Tags: android, google-maps, android-lifecycle, supportmapfragment

I have displayed google map on my fragment.
I would like to know if I have to explicit call the lifecycle method of the mMapFragment (onResume/onPause...)in order to correctly handle the lifecycle of that fragment.
If I do not have to call them I would like to know how it is handle the life cycle of SupportMapFragment.

public class RunsMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_runs_map,null);
        initializeMap();
        return view;
    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container,mMapFragment).commit();
            mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }
}
```